# How to know the command run by a process?

Tags: process, wget, ps, background-process

I have run multiple commands in different time as background process.

`wget -r url1 &`
`wget -r url2 &`
`..............`
`..............`

The result of `ps -e` shows 2 process named `wget`---

```
     2552 ?        00:00:01 wget
     2576 ?        00:00:00 wget
     ......        .............
     ......        .............
```

Now, I want to kill the process which is executing `url2`. How can I know which process runs which `url`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `-e` option for `ps` command, use `-f` option.

```
user1    14298 13518  0 00:11 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 100
user1    14299 13518  0 00:11 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 50
```

This way you will see the parameters passed to the command as well, in your case different URLs

Answer (score 1):

If this was done in an interactive shell setting, the second backgrounded job can be killed with `kill %2`.

If this was done in a shell script, you can record the PIDs and signal them thusly:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://example.com/bigfile1 &
pid1=$!
wget http://example.com/biggerfile2 &
pid2=$!
# Time passes..
# Impatience intensifies...
kill $pid2
```

If you want to see the full command lines (and environments) of your current session, you can use `ps ex`.